# pip install openpyxl - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'et_xmlfile'

Tags: python, pip, spyder, openpyxl, modulenotfounderror

The question or similar ones were often asked before, but I didn't come to a solution.
I'm trying to install openpyxl by `pip install openpyxl` (already tried `pip3` install `openpyxl`) and always get the error message below. 
I also already tried to install `jdcal` (worked) and `et_xmlfile` (didn't work, same error) separately beforehand.
I use `--no-cache-dir` because the output before was `Using cached et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz (8.4 kB)`, so I guessed that this could be the problem, but it wasn't.

I'm using `Spyder 4.x`.

I'd really appreciate your help ...

---

```
C:\Users\Lina\Spyder\Python\Scripts>pip3 install --no-cache-dir C:\Users\Lina\Spyder\Python\Lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz
Processing c:\users\lina\spyder\python\lib\site-packages\et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz

 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\lina\spyder\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Lina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-pa5jygs_\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Lina\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-pa5jygs_\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-nitpcy2b'
         cwd: C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-pa5jygs_\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Lina\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-pa5jygs_\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
        from et_xmlfile import (
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'et_xmlfile'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: try installing et_xmlfile with pip first (or manually if it doesn't work). Note that et_xmlfle is not at version 1.1.0

Answer (score 0):

I solved on Windows 10 in this way:

1. download `et_xmlfile` from its official repository (https://pypi.org/project/et-xmlfile/#files)
2. extract and copy all its content in <python_setup_dir>/Lib/
3. open the `et_xmlfile` and then open `setup.py` in py ide
4. from menu run>run...customized, specify the Line Arguments `build`
5. from menu run>run...customized, specify the Line Arguments `install`

let me know if this works even for you too.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit of an old question, but I just ran:

```
pip install openpyxl --upgrade
```

and it installed the package. You can try uninstalling openpyxl first if it doesnt work: `pip uninstall openpyxl`.